# Is the Cesaro Operator normal?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, cesaro-summable

The Cesàro operator $T:ℓ_p→ℓ_p$ is defined by 
      $$(Tx)_k=(1/k)\sum_{j=1}^k x_j$$
where $x=(x_j)$.
Is this operator normal?

Comment: What's the meaning of "normal" here?

Comment: @xavierm02 what is the pairing you are using? $\ell_p$ is not a hilbert space under the obvious norm.

Comment: @xavierm02: and what do the symbols $\langle x,y\rangle$ mean, for $x,y\in\ell_p$? Besides the fact that what you wrote, in the case of Hilbert spaces, means $T$ selfadjoint and not normal.

Answer (score 2):

In the case $p = 2$, we first compute $T^*$. Noting that

$$ \langle Tx, y\rangle = \sum_{k} \sum_{j = 1}^k x_j \bar{y}_k / k = \sum_{j} \sum_{k = j}^\infty x_j \bar{y}_k / k $$

we have that

$$ (T^*y)_j = \sum_{k = j}^\infty \frac{y_k}{k} $$

So we have that

$$ (T T^* y)_\ell = \sum_{j = 1}^\ell \sum_{k = j}^\infty \frac{y_k}{k \ell} $$

and

$$ (T^* T x)_\ell = \sum_{k = \ell}^\infty \sum_{j = 1}^k \frac{x_j}{k^2} $$

Testing against the sequence $(1,0,0,\ldots)$ you see the two are clearly not equal. So even in the $\ell_2$ case the operator is not normal.

In the $\ell_p$ case I don't even know what "normal" would mean.